# Click the close button will close all bootstrap model

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-4

For those code, there have a button "Launch modal" to open the Model, then in Model, also have a button "Launch modal2" to open a new model(just call model2) on Model. 
When I click the close button on model2, all of the Model will de dismiss. How can I fix that?
Please note that I need to put model2 in Model for display data.
Thanks.
http://jsfiddle.net/ve42xs6w/

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div><div class="container"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal2</a>
          <div class="modal" id="myModal2" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Second Modal title</h4>
                  </div><div class="container"></div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are putting the second modal inside of the first modal. Bootstrap just closes all modals that the close button is inside of, so if you nest them the second close button will close all outside modals.
To fix this you can just move the whole `div#myModal2` down under the first `div#myModal` so they are separate elements.
Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/e92o1j3s/3/